# How to write Cocoa NSWindow code in C++ syntax?

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I have following code in a .mm file:

```
NSRect mainDisplayRect;// = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];
    mainDisplayRect.origin.x = x;
    mainDisplayRect.origin.y = y;
    mainDisplayRect.size.width = width;
    mainDisplayRect.size.height = height;
    NSWindow *fullScreenWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect: mainDisplayRect styleMask: NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:YES];
```

Could someone please help especially regarding how to initialize **fullScreenWindow** pointer as according to c++ syntax, just simply need conversion in C++ syntax. Or will this compile successfully even with C++ compiler(i.e when written as it is in .cpp file, without any modification.). I don't know much about objective-C code syntax. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't translate that to C++. The Cocoa framework doesn't have a binding to C++.

You can use Objective-C++, which is a superset of C++. So, the code you showed would compile just fine as Objective-C++. You can use a .mm file extension or specify the language using command-line options when you invoke the compiler. But that's not really what you asked.

In theory, you could deconstruct the Objective-C code into calls to the Objective-C run time library (e.g. `objc_msgSend()`, etc.), but that would be awful and almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Could you please also tell whether the above code is objective-C or objective-C++?

Comment: The code is effectively both/either. It works in both languages. Objective-C consists of certain additions to C. Objective-C++ consists of those same additions to C++. The code you showed has elements which work fine in C or C++, such as the declaration of `mainDisplayRect` as a variable of type `NSRect`, which a typedef of a struct, and the setting of its fields. The line which declares and initializes `fullScreenWindow` uses Objective-C(++) additions which are the same in either language.

Comment: Hi @Ken Thomases, again thanks for the answer. One last question, can a .mm file be compiled successfully in a c++ xcode project?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "C++ project". Projects are not tied to languages. They can include components from multiple languages. An Objective-C++ source file can be linked into the same binary as a C++ source file, yes. That's part of the reason for Objective-C++ to exist, to bridge the Objective-C and C++ worlds. For example, an Objective-C++ file could have a pure C++ interface and use Objective-C-isms internally. Or vice versa.